# Determining whether to use one line or two in linear regression

Tags: r, regression, anova

Basically I'm attempting to recreate the results of an example from class in R. What I'm trying to do is decide whether it's best to use a single regression line for an entire data set or two lines based on a categorical variable. The teacher indicates there are three steps to this:

1. Determine if two different lines are required
2. If yes, determine if they differ in slope
3. If yes, determine if they differ in intercept

Here is my data:

```
> example
   Predictor Response Group
1         21       11     A
2         24       21     A
3         26       23     A
4         29       29     A
5         35       34     A
6         45       51     A
7         51       59     A
8         68       73     A
9         72       83     A
10        76       95     A
11        17       11     B
12        21       55     B
13        26       34     B
14        28       44     B
15        32       26     B
16        36       34     B
17        40       15     B
18        45       21     B
19        51       16     B
20        68       21     B
```

I've realized that if I add the interaction and group terms to the model:

```
ex_mod <- lm(Response ~ Predictor,data = example)
ex_mod2 <- lm(Response ~ Predictor + Group + Predictor:Group,data = example)
```

And then perform ANOVA on this. I get the right answer for step 1:

```
> anova(ex_mod,ex_mod2)
Analysis of Variance Table

Model 1: Response ~ Predictor
Model 2: Response ~ Predictor + Group + Predictor:Group
  Res.Df    RSS Df Sum of Sq     F    Pr(>F)    
1     18 6616.4                                 
2     16 1583.8  2    5032.6 25.42 1.078e-05 ***
```

Which means I need different lines, but now I need to know if they differ in slope or y-intercept or both. And here is where I'm stuck. I cant seem to get the right answer (F = 293.17 for slope, and F = 170.77 for intercept).

The teacher indicates that the next steps are: 1) to generate RSS in which the slope is fixed,but the y-intercepts are allowed to vary; and 2) generate RSS in which the y-intercept is fixed, but the slopes are allowed to vary.

I apologize if the question is confusing or simplistic, but I dont know how to proceed from here.

Thanks

Comment: But its not the stats that are the problem but implementing them in R. My class doesnt use R, this is my own initiative.

Comment: I disagree, still seems like a stats question. Do you know what mathematical formula you did fit? Do you know what mathematical formulas you want to fit? Do you know what what `Group` and `Predictor:Group` mean in the R formula you did fit? If your class notes aren't helpful, you could try reading `?formula` or `?lm`.

Comment: The `anova` is not particularly useful here (at least in part because it is not telling you what you say it is). You might find the `summary` function more informative. both for the inferential steps and for moving toward the display of results.